# Ubuntu 13.04 Sound Problem after following weird commands

Tags: 13.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

After launching a few commands :

```
echo autospawn = no >> ~/.config/pulse/client.conf  #use ~/.pulse/client.conf on Ubuntu <= 12.10
killall pulseaudio
$LANG=C pulseaudio -vvvv --log-time=1 > ~/pulseverbose.log 2>&1
```

My sound does not work. (just with the speakers, with headphones it works but I can not change the volume)

The sound icon on the top right corner does show a speaker with a single non continuous line.

I can not change the volume; it is frozen. There can be an extremely low output of the sound (I hear something but I am not sure...) It does not show a single output device that is avalaible, not even the "dummie". I have tried to reset pulseaudio, alsa, remove it, purging it, reinstalling it, without having success.

EDIT: I have tried launching pulseaudio via the terminal. It worked :D

However, I am very surprised why it does not automatically start at the start of the computer. Any ideas ?
Here the console output :

```
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/home/simonm/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/home/simonm/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/home/simonm/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/home/simonm/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove configuration files you had created to reset to default settings of pulseaudio:

```
mv ~/.config/pulse/client.conf ~/.config/pulse/client.conf.old
```

or (if you are on Ubuntu 12.10 or earlier)

```
mv ~/.pulse/client.conf ~/.pulse/client.conf.old
```

After that you will have to log out and restart your session to start pulseaudio with its 
default settings.

<sup>**Note:** if this does not resolve your issue you may have broken your sound system with your attempts to purge it.</sup>

Basically in the first command you told it to not `autospawn` (i.e. restart by default).